# Access key vault in azure synapse analytical pipeline notebook

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault, azure-synapse

I have a secret saved in the Azure key vault and want to access it in the Synapse analytical pipeline
when I run the manual notebook it does not give an error and I get my secret in the output of the notebook. Still, when I run the notebook through a pipeline it gives an error, and an error message is attached below while I have already added the access policy in my Azure key vault and my email ID, as well as my workspace name.
[Error Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcBGr.png)

I aim to get the key vault secret value in my notebook through the pipeline run not manually.

```
from notebookutils import mssparkutils
mssparkutils.credentials.getSecret('kv-dp-WorkspaceName','TestNoteBook')
```

The above two lines of code give me the secret value when I run the notebook manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get secret by calling notebook in pipeline you need to spacify key vault liked service name in the code.

- First crate linked service to particular Key vault below:
  [image]
- In key vault assingn appropeiate permission to managed identitiy of service principal of syampse workspace:
  [image]
- Then Run below code in synaps notebook

```
from notebookutils import mssparkutils
mssparkutils.credentials.getSecret('key vault name','secret name','linkedservice name')
```

**Notebook executed from pipeline successfully:**

[image]

Comment: I did the same but faced the error which I attached the link to the main question above Error Details. also my project is lined with github

Comment: second, i check out the syntax from help, which is getSecret(akvName, secret): returns AKV secret for a given akvName, secret key
Can you please confirm that you used linker service name in your syntax